# why main goroutine always be the second to be invoked

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

```
package main
import (
  "sync"
  "time"
  )
func main() {
  var wg sync.WaitGroup

  wg.Add(1)

  go func() {         //A
    wg.Wait()
    println("wait exit")
  }()

  go func() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    wg.Done()
  }()

  wg.Wait()
  println("main exit")
}
```

---

result:

```
wait exit
main exit
```

Why don't main goroutine execute println("main exit") first, and main thread dead and then discard A goroutine?
It keeps printing like the result shows

Answer (score 2):

Chance.

There's nothing in the language spec that says your "wait exit" should execute either before or after "main exit".

Chances are if you run the program enough times, sometimes "main exit" will run first.  But also maybe not. The results are not defined, and depend on the runtime state and implementation. As such results may even change between Go versions.

Comment: I have tried many times, if this is determined by chance, I thought maybe it should appear at least once.

Comment: @JunAn Try running the program with -race. The runtime will somewhat randomize the order in which goroutines are run when compiled with -race. Using -race I get different outputs most of the time.

Comment: @JunAn: the order is not defined, which means that by chance the current runtime implementation may still be influencing the order an a consistent way. If you're using the playground, you're just retrieving the same cached result every time. Simply don't rely on order where you don't create order.

Comment: In addition to the answer and comments above, adding `runtime.LockOSThread()` to the 2 printing goroutines and running it many times, I had a run where only the "main exit" was printed (and the program terminated before the other text could have been printed).

Comment: For the record, on single-core systems, goroutine scheduling _is_, for the most part, deterministic.  There's a chance on entering a function for that goroutine to be rescheduled (to prevent thread saturation by a continually spinning routine), but otherwise the scheduler has consistent rules for when a goroutine swap can occur (on blocking channel operation, network calls, sleep, and a few others).  This behavior just isn't well-documented, nor is it defined in the spec, and thus the implementation can be changed without notice and without breaking the backwards compatibility guarantee.